WinApi. Обработка результата функции GetWindowLong
Начал изучать основу WinAPI (ну как начал, задание от препода по универу).
Задание. Необходимо сделать так, чтобы условие ниже заработало, если заменить оператор "&" на "==".
// Функция обработки сообщений
...
...
case WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK: {
        if (GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE) & WS_POPUP) {...}

Из ответов авторов на мой вопрос, понял, что  функция GetWindowLong возвращает 32-битное слово, где биты являются флагами. Что значит необходимо при использовании оператора "==" вместо "&", обработать GetWindowLong так, чтобы остался только необходимый мне бит. Как это сделать (если поставлены флаги: WS_POPUPWINDOW | WS_CAPTION | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_VISIBLE | WS_SYSMENU)?
Заранее благодарю за выделенное время.
Уточнения. Код сам по себе рабочий, однако задание по замене оператора "&" на "==", это прикол от преподавателя, которое нужно сделать.

Вы хотите, чтобы мы прочли весь этот код?

как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример

Вопрос непонятен. Зачем заменять выделение нужного флага с помощью & на что-то ещё? Вы можете результат сравнить if ((GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) & WS_EX_TOPMOST) == WS_EX_TOPMOST)

"чтобы он заработал" - ¿А сейчас он не работает? ¿В чем это проявляется?

Подробнее о замене "&" на "==" в строке с GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE) & WS_POPUP). Данный код работает исправно, однако данная замена необходима мне для ответа на вопрос преподавателя (как сделать, чтобы данная строка работала с == вместо &). Заранее благодарю за выделенное время.

Зависит от битового представления WS_POPUP и результата, возвращаемого функцией GetWindowLong()

@ID420, в условии if (GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE) & WS_POPUP) знак & -- это оператор AND. Т.е. оно эквивалентно if ((VALUE1 AND VALUE2) != 0) и проверяет, что определённый флаг входит в состав остального набора флагов, возвращаемых функцией GetWindowLong. А Ваша проверка GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE) == WS_POPUP выполнится лишь в частном случае, когда весь набор флагов представлен только одним значением WS_POPUP, т.е. скорее всего никогда. "Вместо" работать не будет, только "вместе", как в примере @MBo. Или имеет место быть недопонимание: наше - Вас или Ваше - преподавателя

"Как это сделать (если поставлены флаги: WS_POPUPWINDOW | WS_CAPTION | WS_...." -- может преп хочет что-то вроде if ((GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE) & WS_POPUPWINDOW)  == WS_POPUPWINDOW)? Т.е. (это актуально если WS_POPUPWINDOW это не один бит) он хочет проверить, что все тестируемые биты установлены

А разве (GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE) & WS_POPUPWINDOW) и ((GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE) & WS_POPUPWINDOW)  == WS_POPUPWINDOW) это не одно и тоже?

@ID420, конечно нет. (v & mask) -- это означает, что есть хотя бы один единичный бит из mask, который установлен в v, а (v & mask) == mask -- это значит все единичные биты из mask установлены в v. Понятно, что если (v & mask) == mask истина, то и (v & mask) тоже всегда истина, а вот обратное не верно  / (кстати, если хотите, чтобы о вашем комментарии сообщили, то ставьте @nickname в начале комментария)

При вызове функции GetWindowLong с параметром GWL_STYLE вы получаете результат - 32-битное слово, биты которого являются флагами, показывающими, с каким стилем было создано данное окно. Если при его создании (CreateWindow) был указан флаг WS_POPUP (0x800000000L), то и в результате будет установлен самый старший бит.
Чтобы проверить этот бит, накладывается соответствующая маска с помощью побитового AND.
В данном конкретном случае ( только для этого флага) можно проверить, что число отрицательное.
Можно выполнить сдвиг вправо и проверить, что результат равен -1
  (GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE) >> 31) == -1

Это обусловлено тем, что для знакового числа выполняется арифметический сдвиг, при котором знаковый бит заполняет освободившееся место, и при наличии флага WS_POPUP получится 0xFFFFFFFF==-1
Но всё это - обработка результата GetWindowLong (как и с AND), без обработки не получится сравнить на равенство, потому что в нём установлено ещё несколько флагов. Разве что вы точно знаете весь набор флагов, раз сами создаёте окно...

Добавлю ещё один момент, который нужно знать. Конструкция
if (GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE) & WS_POPUP) {...}

не совсем корректная. Например, если проверить таким образом флаг
if (GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE) & WS_OVERLAPPED) {...}

то можно получить отрицательный результат, и это при том, что окно было создано перекрывающимся. Правильно:
if ((GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE) & WS_OVERLAPPED) == WS_OVERLAPPED) {...}

(дело в значении флага WS_OVERLAPPED   0x00000000L)

Можете объяснить, какая битовая запись получится, если известен набор флагов для окна с дескриптором hWnd (флаги: WS_POPUPWINDOW | WS_CAPTION | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_VISIBLE | WS_SYSMENU).

по идее, как раз этот набор, объединенный побитовым ИЛИ, и должен получиться, но я не исключаю, что какие-то еще биты по умолчанию могут быть установлены, не проверял. Сами значения флагов здесь https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-styles, все биты в старшем слове
